# Create a view controller outside of storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I need a small tutorial video to our iOS project which can be accessed from multiple view controllers(screens). I don't want to break dozens of segues to add this tutorial, as it would cause a nightmare. Would the best way to do this, is to create a pop up View Controller which does not have to be added to the storyboard? If so, how can I do that ?

Comment: you can create another storyboard, and you do PUSH and POP operation programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XIB file, without integrating it with storyboard.

Follow these steps to create separate XIB (with Viewcontroller file).

Create new file: Xcode >> New >> File

[image]

Select `Cocoa Touch Class`

[image]

Provide a view controller name and enable XIB option

[image]

**Now, Open your XIB (View Controller):**

```
var viewController = TestViewController(nibName: "TestViewController", bundle: nil)

 // Present
 self.present(viewController, animated: true) {

 }

 //push
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

I suggest to use push navigation. It will automatically add navigation bar and back button to your controller

Comment: but how would I call this xib file from different View Controllers?

Comment: Wait, will provide you complete solution.

Comment: I tried this, but the problem is that my TutorialViewController does not inheret that tab controller up at the top which all View Controllers automatically inheret. How to do that?

Comment: Unable to understand exact issue. Please explain in detail, what do you exactly want? Share me snapshot of design what you exact need to do?

Comment: every view controller has a menu bar at the top with options "back" and "continue" , they all automatically inherit this because the story board is using a tab view controller. But, my xib file is created outside of the story board, so now it does not inherit anything.

Comment: What do you use? `present` or `push`. Use `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)`. It will automatically add navigation bar and back button to your controller.

Comment: hehehe.. yes.. thanks, I missed that. It works now.

Answer (score 3):

Create your tutorial view controller with separate `.xib` file.

Through New File menu:

[image]

And then check highlighted box:

[image]

And when you need to present your view controller you need to initialize it from nib (xib) file you just created.

```
let vc = TutorialViewController(nibName: "TutorialViewController", bundle: nil)
present(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: but how would I call this xib file from different View Controllers?

Comment: @monekypox121 See the edited answer.

Comment: I tried this, but the problem is that my TutorialViewController does not inheret that tab controller up at the top which all View Controllers automatically inheret. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a new View Controller ("scene") to your existing Storyboard, but *not* attach any segues to it. Then, when you want to show it from anywhere in your app, you can:

```
    if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopUpTutorial") as? PopUpTutorial {
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

You can also create an additional Storyboard file and build your "Tutorial" screen(s) there. Then you would change the code to:

```
    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Tutorial", bundle: nil)
    if let vc = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopUpTutorial") as? PopUpTutorial {
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

This does not have to be done in a separate `xib` file.

Answer (score 0):

**Spets to follow:**

1. Select file new Xcode Toolbar
2. Now select New
3. Than Select File
4. Select "Cocoa touch class" under iOS>Source
5. Click next
6. Type "Class name" which you wants
7. Select subclass "UIViewController"
8. Click Also Create a "XIB"
9. Select Language "Swift" or "Objective c"
10. Now Click Next.
11. Finally you have Created a Controller.